# NUnit Integration With Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: nunit, microsoft-test-manager

I can import test cases to Microsoft Test Manager from unit test assembly created in Visual Studio using tcm testcase import command.When I try to import test cases but using NUnit assembly the command fails saying "No Tests found to import".Is there another way by which I can import test cases created in Nunit to Microsoft Test Manager?

Answer (score 3):

We were able to pick up our NUnit tests fine using `tcm` to import to MTM, by adding a `TestMethodAttribute` to our NUnit test methods.

For example:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  public class SuccessTests
  {
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod] //<-- here
    [Test] 
    public void Add()
    { 
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Using the fully-qualified reference to `TestMethod` was preferred over a using directive, since several of the class names clash between either implementation so this would introduce an ambiguity.

With the above in place, we were then able to successfully call `tcm.exe` to import these tests:

```
tcm testcase /import /collection:CollectionURL /teamproject:project /storage:path
```

Answer (score 2):

No, your tests need to be in the MSTest framework in order to be integrated with the Microsoft Test Manager.
If you want to use MTM you need to convert your NUnit Test cases into MSTests.
You can refer [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eeb42224-bc1f-476d-98b4-93d0daf44aad/converting-nunit-test-project-to-ms-test) URL in order to achieve this.